# How to fix install blog extension last step error?

Tags: magento2.2.6

How to fix install blog extension last step error?
please check this screenshot.
http://prntscr.com/li3e5p

i'm facing many errors on this server(platform.cloudways.com).

Comment: Which blog extension you are installing?

Comment: i put extensions file in app/code/Magefan/blog folder https://marketplace.magento.com/magefan-module-blog.html